# How to make common writable folder in a domain, where other domain, php script able to write images for common use from many domains

Tags: php, linux

I have 2 domains with document roots, say:

- A point to www/domainA/public_html
- B point to www/domainB/public_html.

Now I want to able to write a image folder in A document root folder, from a PHP script residing in B document root. But it always gives a permission denied error.

I have tried to make all files proper writing permissions in A,s document root, provide same user on both domain and group. But still not able to correct the problem.

How I can make, 2 or more document root able to write files in a common resource folder?

Comment: Make a folder that is group-writable and add both users of both domains to that same group.

Comment: i have tried, but still showing permission deny. /home/domA/public_html/pub/files and /home/domB/public_html/ have grpadmin:grpadmin same user/group set , but in domB php running from browser not able to create file in domA files folder .

Comment: If you need to do it from the browser, the web-server user (apache, www, etc.) would need to have access as well so it would have to be a member of that group as well.